# Async method to read and write to XML file

Tags: c#, xml, asynchronous, xamarin.forms

I am using DependencyService in android/ios and windows phone to write and read a XML file in my Xamarin.forms project. I am referring to [working with files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/).

I was able to implement the function given in the example but what I actually want is reading and writing to a XML file.

I followed a usual c# procedure to read and write to xml file but getting errors as the method is async.

I have never used async await methods so not sure how to go about it.

Here is what I tried:

```
public async Task SaveTextAsync(string filename, string text)
{
    ApplicationData data = new ApplicationData();
    ApplicationVersion version = new ApplicationVersion();
    version.SoftwareVersion = "test";
    data.ApplicationVersion = version;

    XmlSerializer writer =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationData));
    System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);

    writer.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();
}

public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync(string filename)
{
    var path = CreatePathToFile(filename);
    ApplicationData cars = null;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationData));
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path);
    cars = (ApplicationData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    reader.Close();
}
string CreatePathToFile(string filename)
{
    var docsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    return Path.Combine(docsPath, filename);
}
```

**Edit**

Working Read and write to txt file code is here:

```
public async Task SaveTextAsync (string filename, string text)
{
    var path = CreatePathToFile (filename);
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText (path))
        await sw.WriteAsync(text);
}

public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync (string filename)
{
    var path = CreatePathToFile (filename);
    using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
        return await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Comment: exact error you get?

Comment: The first method (SaveTextAsync) doesn't give any error but second one (LoadTextAsync) does.
`Error 5 'LoadTextAsync(string)': not all code paths return a value`

Comment: It looks like you have a two port application where you are read/write a stream and write/read a file. Normally the async portion of the code would be on the stream and not the file.

Comment: @jdweng Could you please explain how to do it.

Comment: The best example of async method is the socket examples at msdn.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Check this example . https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/10/simple-async-await-example-for-asynchronous-programming/

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I managed to get it work. Here is my code:

```
public async Task SaveTextAsync(string filename)
{
    var path = CreatePathToFile(filename);
    ApplicationData data = new ApplicationData();
    ApplicationVersion version = new ApplicationVersion();
    version.SoftwareVersion = "test version";
    data.ApplicationVersion = version;
    XmlSerializer writer =
        new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationData));
    System.IO.FileStream file = System.IO.File.Create(path);
    writer.Serialize(file, data);
    file.Close();

}

public async Task<ApplicationData> LoadTextAsync(string filename)
{
    var path = CreatePathToFile(filename);

    ApplicationData records = null;
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer specifying type and namespace.
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ApplicationData));

        // A FileStream is needed to read the XML document.
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(fs);

        // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
        records = (ApplicationData)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        fs.Close();
    });
    return records;
}
```

Comment: It's useless as its still sync because there is no await inside the task.